# How to load Qt Designer UI file

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, uic

```
import sys
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5 import uic


class WelcomeScreen(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(WelcomeScreen, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("welcomescreen.ui",self)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
welcome = WelcomeScreen()
widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
widget.addWidget(welcome)
widget.setFixedHeight(800)
widget.setFixedWidth(1200)
widget.show()
try:
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
except:
    print("Exiting")
```

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'welcomescreen.ui'

Can anyone please explain this?
I am fairly new to PyQt5 and got stuck in this problem.
Your kind help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is 'welcomescreen.ui' in your root or in a sub directory?

Comment: Assuming your ui file is in the same direcory as your main.py script: `import os; uic.loadUi(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "welcomescreen.ui"))`.